# Selecting the element below with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

[image]

I tried this:

```
$( "#navbar li .arrow" ).click(function() {
  alert("worked");
  $(this).closest('ul').css("display", "block");
});
```

To select the `ul` element under `.arrow`. But nothing happen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you tried .next() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method fetches the ancestor elements, in your case the `ul` is the next sibling of the `.arrow` element

You need to use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) here

```
$(this).next().css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.next()` if the `ul` is always under `.arrow`

```
$(this).next()
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is used to select the nearest matching parent element. To select a sibling use `next()`:

```
$( "#navbar li .arrow" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` selects the closest parent object, you need to use `next()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.next()` here:

```
$(this).next().css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$( "#navbar li a.arrow" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').css("display", "block");
});
```